# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' :dbcp.SQLNestedException

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7, database-connection, jndi

I am unable to get database connection in Tomcat7. i am using oracle linux as a OS. Below are my DB connection pool configuration.

**server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

<Resource name="jdbc/weblogin01"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="${resource.weblogin01.url}"
    username="${resource.weblogin01.username}"
    password="${resource.weblogin01.password}"
    initialSize="2"
    maxActive="20"
    maxIdle="10"
    minIdle="2"
    maxWait="-1" 
    testWhileIdle="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="20000"
    validationQuery="select * from dual" />

<Resource name="jdbc/osswebportal"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="${resource.osswebportal.url}"
    username="${resource.osswebportal.username}"
    password="${resource.osswebportal.password}" 
    initialSize="1"
    maxActive="20"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="-1"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
    validationQuery="select * from dual" />
```

**web.xml**

```
 <resource-ref>
>         <res-ref-name>jdbc/osswebportal</res-ref-name>
>         <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>         <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>         <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
>     </resource-ref>
>     <resource-ref>
>         <res-ref-name>jdbc/weblogin01</res-ref-name>
>         <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>         <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>         <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
>     </resource-ref>
```

**context.xml**

```
 <ResourceLink global="jdbc/weblogin01" name="jdbc/weblogin01" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/osswebportal" name="jdbc/osswebportal" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

i have also define all the db details in tomcat's catalina.properties

> resource.osswebportal.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.com:1522:GPSP
>   resource.osswebportal.username=User
>
> resource.osswebportal.password=password
>
> resource.weblogin01.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@test2:1522:GSPS
>   resource.weblogin01.username=User1
>
> resource.weblogin01.password=Password

- And also i have placed the jdbc jar in both tomcat's lib directory as well Applications's WEB_INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

put the Driver Jar file in the server lib folder, I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by server lib folder. I am sorry. i didn't get you

Comment: in your welogic domain folder there will be lib folder put the oracle driver in it

Comment: if you asking me to add jdbc jar in application's lib directory, then it is there as well and also in application's WEB-INT/lib directoyr. Still not clear about webogic domain folder

Comment: in your web logic home folder their must be some thing like domains, in it you might be find domain1 folder or what ever you name during you installation, or configuration of the web logic, in that folder you must have lib folder make sure that you have the driver in it too.

Comment: I am using Tomcat7 as a app server. there is nothing called domains direcotry